# Why the finite subgroups of $GL_n$ is closed with respect to Zariski topology?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $GL_n$ be the group of all $n$ by $n$ invertible matrices. Why the finite subgroups of $GL_n$ is closed with respect to Zariski topology? Are the zeros defined by some equations? Thank you very much.

Comment: Any finite subset of an affine variety is closed.

Comment: A single point is closed (=the zero set of linear polynomials of the form $x_i-a_i$) => any finite set is closed

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much. But the points of $GL_n$ are matrices. What are the polynomial equations in this case?

Comment: Do you know how $GL_n$ has been identified with a variety in the first place?

Comment: $x_{ij}-a_{ij}$